# Auto formatting html in a template

Tags: typescript, format, webstorm

Is there any way to automatically format/tab html code wrapped in backticks (`)?

Suppose I'm using an HTML template:

```
@Component({
   selector: "xyz",
   template: htmlTemplate
})
```

And for simplicity's sake, I have a different file that holds my html for the template:

```
export const htmlTemplate = `
<div>
<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
</div>
`
```

thats what the html would look like if I dont manually tab every line that deserves a sweet sweet tab (or 4 spaces for you heathens).
However, I'd like the code to auto format, say, like this:

```
export const htmlTemplate = `
<div>
   <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
`
```

Does WebStorm offer me any feature like this?

The autoformat shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> doesn't seem to do the trick.

Also while we're talking about templates, is there any way to remove that ghastly green background appearing around the templated code (Darkula theme)?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The green color come from **Settings > Editor > Color & Fonts > General** then in the right tab **Code > Injected language fragment**

To auto-format this kind of fragment, you have to edit it separatly. Place your cursor anywhere inside the template, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> then choose **Edit HTML fragment**. In the new tab you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.